# Pause a task execution in a worker class if a task is getting executed in another class

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have two worker classes which executes a task.So basically both the tasks are scheduled where 1 task runs every hour and another every minute.

What i want is when the hourly task is running the minute task should pause its execution. I am not sure how i do this?

I have the below code in the worker classes

```
public override Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("iLevel Refresh delta cache background service is stopped.");
            return base.StopAsync(cancellationToken);
        }

        public override async Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            
            await RefreshCache();
            await base.StartAsync(cancellationToken);
        }
        protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
        {
            while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                await Task.Delay(AppSettings.Current.CacheRefreshDetlaDelay, stoppingToken);
                await RefreshCache();
            }
        }
        public async Task RefreshCache()
        {
            
            _logger.LogInformation("Starting delta cache refresh...");
            var isExceptionLogEnabled = true;
            while (true)
                try
                {
                    using var scope = _scopeFactory.CreateScope();
                    using var iLevel = scope.ServiceProvider.GetService<ILevel>();
                    var cache = scope.ServiceProvider.GetService<CacheService>();
                    var referenceDataService = new ReferenceDataService(iLevel, cache);

                    await referenceDataService.LoadReferenceDeltaDataFromILevel;

                    _logger.LogInformation("Cache refreshed successfully");

                    return;
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    if (isExceptionLogEnabled)
                    {
                        _logger.LogError(ex, "Failed to refresh cache");
                        isExceptionLogEnabled = false;
                    }
                    await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
                }
        }
    }
}
```

How do i pause this task when a similar task is running in another worker class.I tried adding a static variable and checking if that variable is true or false. But is there any other way to achieve this?

Comment: I really can't tell how the code in the your question relates to the question itself. There's nothing there that shows what tasks are run every hour and what every minute

Comment: @Enigmativity the code await Task.Delay(AppSettings.Current.CacheRefreshDetlaDelay, stoppingToken); here it defines that the task runs every hour which is defined in appsettings. Also there is a similar class for this which runs every minute

Answer (score 3):

You could use one of many *synchronization primitives* and techniques. Since this is `async` the simplest approach would be a [`SemaphoreSlim`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.semaphoreslim?view=netcore-3.1) (as you can't use a `lock`). This will ensure only one task implementation (term used loosely) can run concurrently

```
private SemaphoreSlim _sync = new SemaphoreSlim(1, 1);

public async Task SomeThing()
{
    
    await _sync.WaitAsync();
    
    try
    {
       // implementation here 
    }
    finally
    {
       _sync.Release();
    }
}
```

<sub>***Note** : If this is a long running task, then `SemaphoreSlim` may not be the best solution as it's based on a `SpinWait` as such will tend to chew cpu cycles waiting to acquire the lock, if this is the case you could use a `Semaphore` or check out [Overview of synchronization primitives](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/threading/overview-of-synchronization-primitives) for other alternatives*.</sub>

Comment: is there any easy way to do this? Like can i somehow check if the other task in worker class is running or not?

Comment: @ashish the term "*easier*" is relative, there are however many easier ways to get this wrong

Comment: I tried using SemaphoreSlim but i dont get the correct number of task that are running, so as i said i have 2 worker class but when i see the output of SemaphoreSlim i see always 1 count instead of 2

Comment: @ashish - Isn't that what you want?

Comment: @Enigmativity Basically i have 2 worker class, First worker class is scheduled to run every hour and other is scheduled to run every minute. So when an hourly task is running i dont want the minute task to run. So here SemaphoreSlim is giving me the data of hourly worker task, i am only getting the info related to minute worker class